# Facebook Invite Friends API for website, how to set a redirect url to my webpage

Tags: javascript, facebook-javascript-sdk

on this page http://www.9lessons.info/2012/07/facebook-invite-friends-api.html#livedemo there is a good tutorial for include a facebook invitation dialog but i have a quetion about it. how i can redirect users to my page after they click on the notification? in the tutorial there is this code: '

```
   if (top.location!= self.location){
      top.location = self.location
   }
</script>`
```

where i have to put this code on my page??

Answer (score 0):

its simple, just adding some function below FB.ui
and then redirecting it to another page with window.location.href="gotourl"

```
          function(response)  {
              var receiverIDs;
              if (response.request)  {
                  window.location.href="gotourl";
                  });
```